# Open source database of malware signatures

Tags: windows, malware, opensource

I'm looking for an open source database of malware signatures/hashes (if possible regularly updated and well documented) that I could use in one of my software for scanning a huge numbers of files (most of them are in the PE format) to check if each of these files are malicious or not.

I don't want to use online scanner because most of them share samples with antivirus companies (like Virustotal) and I would like occasionally check theses files offline.

Comment: you could do it in reverse: you could hash all those files and submit them to VirusTotal's API.

Comment: Thanks for your comment, I've edited my question, sorry for this imprecision. (I would like to check these files offline)

Comment: Why is sharing with AV companies a bad thing. If what you are looking for exists, don't you think each AV company would also tap into it?

Comment: Or are you wanting to craft malware and see if it already exists in some known database?

Comment: The main problem is that even if such a database exists, it would not be a very effective way to find malware. A malware writer could literally change the version number, or add a line of completely useless code, and change the hash. For this reason, most AV software will incorporate some kind of behavior/pattern analysis instead of just mindlessly comparing hashes to a master list.

Comment: Blacklist/Whitelist databases sorted 0-F/00-FF. http://tot-ltd.org/tt/md5hashlist.rar More info at http://tot-ltd.org/techinf.html Yes, I run tot-ltd.org.